# The space of all continuous real functions with compact support

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, function-spaces

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a Locally Compact Hausdorff Topological Space.

Let $C_c(\mathbb{X})$ be the space of all continuous real functions with compact support.

I am looking for a good reference for this space $C_c(\mathbb{X})$.

Is $C_c(\mathbb{X})$ separable?

Comment: It’s not always separable at least in the norm topology. Consider a discrete uncountable space as $X$.

Comment: I'd look for references in measure theory books. Riesz representation theorem to find the dual etc. Rudin's *real and complex analysis*, or Royden are starting points. Or Dunford and Schwarz of course.